# Онлайн магазин на Wordpress. Проблема с версткой

Tags: html, css

Привет всем! Делаю [онлайн шоп](http://financial-side.com/) на Wordpress. Подпиливаю макет. Появилась проблема которую никак не могу решить даже через отладчик Мозиллы. Посмотрите на товары, у них у всех разная высота, изменяя height : auto у елементов ничего не меняется. Прошу совета, желательно с указанием классов, где что поменять, что бы все товары были одинаковые. Большое спасибо заранее!

Comment: Приводите воспроизводимый пример проблемы прямо в вопросе. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Для изображения товара:

```
.grid_item img {
    max-height: 120px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Заранее надо бы позаботиться об одинаковых размера картинок для ваших или чужих товаров.

Comment: Так пробовал, получается все ровно один товар криво: 
http://snag.gy/KmVYz.jpg

Comment: @Vitaliy что значит криво? на одни картинках есть белые поля, на третьей нет этого. В любом случае будет разница, даже если добавить padding контейнеру картинки.

Comment: Я понял, спасибо.